# Deprecated: Function session_unregister() is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\emallportal\admin\library\functions.php on line 89

Tags: php

Why am I getting this error.Kindly help
........
  /*
        Logout a user
    */

```
function doLogout()
{
    if (isset($_SESSION['plaincart_user_id'])) {
        unset($_SESSION['plaincart_user_id']);
        session_unregister('plaincart_user_id'); //line 89
    }

    header('Location: login.php');
    exit;
}
```

Comment: The error says it all, do please try and google before posting questions.

Comment: Exactly @Epodax has already mentioned, error says it all. Because this function no longer works with PHP 5.4 and higher versions.

Comment: You can try to use session_destroy()

Answer (score 0):

Deprecated means, the function no longer exists.

```
session_unregister('plaincart_user_id'); //remove this line

unset($_SESSION['plaincart_user_id']);// this line will unset session for you.
```

Comment: your comment was helpful

Answer (score 0):

It basically means you are using code written for an older version of PHP.

Various features/function change over time due to improvments in PHP and before they are actually removed completely they are set as `deprecated` i.e. warning we will be removing this soon.

[See the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unregister.php) it suggests a correct way of destroying a session variable.

> Note:
>
> If $_SESSION (or $HTTP_SESSION_VARS for PHP 4.0.6 or less) is used, use unset() to unregister a session variable. Do not unset() $_SESSION itself as this will disable the special function of the $_SESSION superglobal.